# Php Form in iframe

Tags: php, forms, iframe

I created a php form in inscription.html, and when I do use this form in iframe of  another page
`<iframe class="ipadp-pos" src="Inscription.html" width="618" height="800"> </iframe>` 
it is blocked I can not write in the input

Comment: Do you have some more code to look at? And a PHP form in HTML?

Comment: Actually you don't create a PHP form but an HTML form that call a PHP script on submit... Anyway... You should post your `inscription.html` form and your php script. Also, do you have errors in console ?

Comment: What does that mean: "it is blocked". And what does that mean: "I can not write in the input"? We cannot help if you only give hints.

Comment: @arkascha : I can see the form but can not write

Comment: Ok. You cannot "focus" on the input. So this is not a PHP problem. Maybe CSS ?

Comment: Oh Thaaaaaaaank's .. i'm sorry :$:$ ( Problem in CSS :$ )

Comment: @user2541980 have you put type="text" at input?

Comment: if it was only CSS problem and problem is resolved: Brewal put your comment as answer and user2541980 mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: @user2541980 Ok I wrote down my comment as an answer. You can now accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot focus on an input in the iFrame, it seems like it is a **CSS issue**.

Try finding what could be prevent the focus in your stylesheet (i.e. some transparent div over the iFrame).